# self-referential many-to-many relationship in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-nova

I have a table called `things` that has a pivot table `thing_thing`.  Obviously, this is a self-referential many-to-many relationship.

I have the following methods defined in the `Thing` model:

```
  public function parentOf (){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Thing::class, 'thing_thing', 'parent_id', 'child_id');
  }
  public function childOf(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Thing::class, 'thing_thing', 'child_id', 'parent_id');
  }
```

My `thing_thing` migration looks like this:

```
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('thing_thing', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->string('message')->nullable();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('child_id')->nullable();
      $table->unique(['parent_id', 'child_id']);
      $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('things')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->foreign('child_id')->references('id')->on('things')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
  }
```

I can't figure out a way to require that the user specify, when attaching a `thing` to another `thing`, whether it should be a child or a parent.  My nova resource has the following:

```
  public function fields(Request $request)
  {
    return [
      ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
      Text::make('label'),
      ID::make('user_id')->hideWhenUpdating()->hideWhenCreating(),
      BelongsToMany::make('Trees', 'trees'),
      BelongsToMany::make('Things', 'childOf'),
      BelongsToMany::make('Things', 'parentOf')
    ];
  }
```

But when attaching the resource, I am not asked whether I want to add a parent or a child.

[image]

How can I specify this?

Comment: i couldnt find any documentation for  BelongsToMany::make() options and signature, or the repository. can you help me with that?

Comment: @Abilogos. This is all I could find, as far as official docs go: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/relationships.html#belongstomany

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are giving the same name to the two Nova relationships. Try giving them different names:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Things-childof', 'childOf'),
BelongsToMany::make('Things-parentof', 'parentOf')
```

Comment: I get the error message 'App\Nova\ThingsChildof' not found.  Isn't the first paramter supposed to correspond to the name of a model?